# What is the Open CL command that actually updates the FPGA of an accelerator card with the bitstream of a .xclbin file created in Vitis?

Tags: opencl, fpga

What is the Open CL command that actually updates the FPGA of an accelerator card with the bitstream included within an .xclbin file created in Vitis with v++ --link -t hw ...?

Otherwise, what are all the possible methods to update the FPGA of an accelerator card with the bitstream included within the .xclbin file created in Vitis?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cl::Program program(context, devices, bins)